# Background .png not showing in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, png

I must be missing something completely obvious here, but can't find anything online to tell me otherwise.

I'm trying to pull a .png into a page using:

```
background:url(img/runner1.png) no-repeat;
```

I know the path is correct because doing the same with a jpg works:

```
background:url(img/header.jpg) no-repeat;
```

It does seem to work in Safari, but not in Chrome or Firefox.

Am I missing something here?

---

**EDIT** -
I am using:

```
#runner1{
background:url(img/runner1.png) no-repeat;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #FFF;
width: 195px;
height: 205px;
}
```

for the following element:

```
<div id="runner1"></div>
```

The page is just running locally from my desktop (so no server involved).

As mentioned previously the paths aren't the problem because a jpg from the same directory works.

Firebug says:

```
runner1.png 
GET
Success
image/png
index.html:201  
0B  
8ms
```

But I can't see the preview or response in Firebug.

Also accessing the file directly returns the same result.

Comment: install firebug on your firefox and see what's going on

Comment: What do you get if you navigate directly to the png?  Is the mime-type set up on the server correctly?

Comment: You're not missing anything. There's no bug in the code you posted and png is supported by all browsers. There must be some other problem. Try using chrome's dom inspector to view the actual HTTP request used to load the png.

Comment: Theres not enough code for us to give a qualified answer/suggestion. In which elements and how do you use the CSS? How do see it doesn't work? More information is needed...

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, but try using the full background specification: `background: transparent url(img/header.png) left top no-repeat;`

Comment: Not sure if this is related, however, I have a png with a solid pixel application of #000000, which fails to display in FF9. Merely shifting that value to #000001 enables the png to display. Here's my bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=714745

Answer (score 5):

Solved!

It would appear that saving PNGs with Photoshop creates a PNG which isn't compatible with chrome or firefox. So instead, I opened the file with Fireworks, re-saved and the pngs are working.

Comment: I'm glad you've fixed your problem, but I'm pretty certain I have used PNGs saved from PS in the past without problems. Got any reference?

Comment: I am having similar issues with PNGs exported from GIMP.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're missing `/`. Try absolute url path.

Comment: Try putting some content into `div`? Like unbreakable space?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with .png files saved from IrfanView: they would not be displayed as a background image before I unchecked the "Save Transparent Color" option in PNG save options. So I guess PNG should be saved without transparent colors to be displayed as background images.